# Python 3 library location issue

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am repeating a tutorial on machine learning. Here is what I get:

```
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1,2],[9,11]])
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], s=150, linewidths=5)
plt.show()


/Users/me/PycharmProjects/ML/venv3/bin/python /Users/me/PycharmProjects/ML/src/kmeans/34_kmeans.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/ML/src/kmeans/34_kmeans.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import style
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/ML/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 207, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/ML/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 201, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

`which python3`

```
/Users/me/PycharmProjects/ML/venv3/bin/python3
```

`which pip3`

```
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `/Users/me/PycharmProjects/ML/venv3/bin/pip3 install python-dateutil`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
python3 -m pip install
```

instead of `pip/pip3` to have more control over which python version you are installing to.

See also [this article](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/)